# integrate modular-admin-html in Laravel 5.5

Tags: templates, laravel-blade, laravel-5.5

Starting a new Laravel 5.5 Project I would like to use as dashboard https://github.com/modularcode/modular-admin-html which is coming with  Handlebars templates.

How would I start to integrate the templates as blade?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to read [templating in laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade)

Download template and put js and css file inside publie/css and /js folder.

Then create one main blade file which has all js and css path.

Then use that main file to create new layout same as template html (just you need to copy only html data).

read below link for more detail.

[intigration of template in laravel](https://adminlte.io/blog/integrate-adminlte-with-laravel)

Comment: thanks for feedback. I found a way beetwen. First I compiled the templates with webpack than I extracted the scss and js files and added to laravels webpack. Seems to work,

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Download the template.

Step2: Just open the template folder then you can see some folder ( like the app, vendor etc.). open the app folder then copy the files contained in the JS and place inside the application public >> JS folder similar copy and paste the contents from template CSS folder to application public>> CSS folder

Step3: Then copy the 'vendor' folder from template and place inside the application  ' public'  folder.

Step4: Then create a new .blade.php file

Step5: Then copy and paste the dashboard code from the template and paste it into the .blade.php

Step6: Then set the route to the dashboard and run.